# Difference between (struct in_addr **) and *(struct in_addr *)

Tags: c++, c

What is the difference between `(struct in_addr **)` and `*(struct in_addr *)`? Please explain clearly with an example.

Comment: In the second, one * is in front of the bracket!

Comment: Rather than just asking for an explanation with an example, you could do well to provide examples of both before stating your question.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `(struct in_addr **)` is *casting* something to a pointer to a pointer to a `struct in_addr`.

The expression `*(struct in_addr *)` casts something to a pointer to a `struct in_addr`, and the *dereferences* that pointer.

---

Example: Lets say you have a function which takes a `void` pointer, i.e. it can take a pointer to *anything*, and you *know* that it's actually a pointer to something else, you could cast that pointer to the correct pointer type:

```
void some_fun(void *ptr)
{
    /* I know that `ptr` is really a pointer to a pointer to a `struct in_addr` */
    /* In other words, an array of pointers to `struct in_addr` */
    struct in_addr **addresses = (struct in_addr **) ptr;

    /* Do something with the array of pointers in `addresses` */
}
```

Other example: If you have another function that also takes a pointer to `void`, but you know that it points to a `struct in_addr`, and you want to convert that to a plain structure without using pointer access:

```
void some_other_fun(void *ptr)
{
    /* I know that `ptr` is really a pointer to a `struct in_addr` */
    /* Copy the data from that structure into my own structure */
    struct in_addr addr = *(struct in_addr *) ptr;

    /* Use `addr`... */
}
```

In the first example, you tell the compiler that one type of pointer is actually a *different* type of pointer.

In the second example, you *first* tell the compiler that the pointer is a different type of pointer (the `(struct in_addr *)` part), *then* you dereference that pointer to get the actual structure with the unary `*` operator.

---

Please not that the type-casting used here is old C-style type-casting. In C++ you would use e.g. [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) instead, like:

```
in_addr** addresses = reinterpret_cast<in_addr**>(ptr);
```

Comment: can you be more clear with an simple example. which helps me lot...

Answer (score 2):

`(struct in_addr **)` is a C-style cast operator converting whatever's to the right of it to a pointer to a pointer to a structure of type `in_addr` (a generic network address.)

`*(struct in_addr *)` is a C-style cast operator followed by a dereferencing operator (read right-to-left), converting whatever's to the right of it to a pointer to an `in_addr`, and then dereferencing that pointer.

Comment: with an example please...

Comment: I am not aware of a meaningful way to provide an example, as this is not an abstract concept. It is like trying to provide an example of Barack Obama, versus providing an example of a Head of State.

Comment: One more doubt guys related to this .addr_list(structure) = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list(char **);   here how we are assigning the char pointer to structure.